# How to set persistent connect with Facebook

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api, facebook-login

I have, on my website, a login with Facebook (API PHP). When the user, click on the "Connect with Facebook" (and all it's ok), I give him a session to log in him on my website ...
But, if the user close his browser,  the session is destroy ...
So, my question is, how to do, to do a persistent connection ...

Here is my code:

```
if(!$member->isLoggedIn()){
    //set Facebook
    $fb_s = Zend_Registry::get('config');
    $config = array(
      'appId' => $fb_s->FACEBOOK->appId,
      'secret' => $fb_s->FACEBOOK->secret
    );
    $facebook = new Facebook($config);
    $user = $facebook->getUser();

    //not logged in on website, but logged in on FB
    if($request->getControllerName() != "login"){
     =========> $user is empty ....
      if($user){
        try{
          $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');
          $membres = new Membre();
          if(!$membre = $membres->getMemberByFB($user_profile['id'])){
            // Need to be re logged in";
            if($a = App_Frontend_Login::LogMeFB($membre) == 1){
              $this->_redirect('/');
            }
          }
        }catch(FacebookApiException $e){
          error_log($e);
          $user = null;
        }
      }
    }
```

Thank you for your help (in advance) ...

Answer (score 0):

If you want to login a user when the php session is over but is logged on facebook, you must use javascript facebook api to check user state in client side.

That's the way for 'remember me' option if you don't want to force user to click in 'connect with facebook' if your app has been already authorized.

Comment: Ok, so I have to use JS Facebook API. Ok, I'll see ... Thank you.